# Encore-dev sever symfony

Tags: symfony, webpack

I am trying to start the server using 
`yarn run encore dev-server --https --port 8003` and 
I get a successful response Project is running at https: // localhost: 8003 / but at this address I get a message

> This site can't be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.

maybe it's the location of the index file, or is it a global setting? help please. [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to replace localhost by 127.0.0.1? Have you check your SSL certificate?

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant ok, it's opened on https://127.0.0.2:8081/ without SSL, thanks, but now i am getting "Cannot GET /" trouble, but think i can solve it)